# What is the difference when a class extend from Handler and Thread? (In Android framework)

Tags: android

What is the difference when a class extend from Handler and Thread?

As described in developer.android.com
`...
Each Handler instance is associated with a single thread and that thread's message queue. 
...`

Does the thread has no message queue ?

Any benefit for a class extend from Handler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a major difference between a `Thread` and a `Handler`.

The Android `Handler` class is used for communication between other `Runnable`/`Thread` and the one that it has been created in.
By posting to a given `Handler`, you can add something for execution on its thread.
You can also send messages from one thread and handle them on another.

Using `Handler`, for example, is the preferred way to do delayed execution, instead of using `TimerTask`. You can also notify your main thread that your worker thread has finished some task, with `Handler` as an alternative of sending `Intent`.

From Android Developer's site:

> There are two main uses for a Handler:
>   (1) to schedule messages and runnables
>   to be executed as some point in the
>   future; and (2) to enqueue an action
>   to be performed on a different thread
>   than your own.

Answer (score 1):

Handlers are able to send and receive messages, perform various operations.

At low level, each handler has its own thread, but Handlers can communicate each other.

For instance, you can have a handler doing some stuff, and the sending results to another handler and so on.